# Salesforce Certified Platform App Builder Exam

Tags: app, developer, certification, dev401

Has anyone here taken the new Force.com Certified App Builder exam? The one which replaced DEV401?
Could I ask for any study materials/tips/exam experience on that?

Comment: Is anything in the study guide not clear ?

Comment: R u looking for an App Builder exam?

Answer (score 2):

I gave my transition exam for App Builder and it is more scenario based and questions are challenging, also includes a lot of new topics compared to dev 401.

You can download the study guide from link below.

http://certification.salesforce.com/SG_CertifiedPlatformAppBuilder.pdf?v=5

In this pdf on the section 5 you can see the Recommended Training and References. you can look at the online courses from your help and training link in production org. These online courses are very useful and most of them are straight questions in your exam. You can search for these online courses or documentation only if you have premier support. Make a note of all these slides for a quick reference 1 day before the exam.

[image]

On the section 6 in the study guide you can see the weighting of each topic in your exam so make sure that you search for all the topics in the salesforce documentation or directly in google.

Comment: My best advice is exactly what @Salesforce Learner stated about googling the study guide topics and reading the relevant Salesforce Documentation that comes up from the search.