# What to Study for 401 Developer Exam

Tags: developer, certification, dev401, help

Hello I am  wondering what  is the most up to date Study Materials for the latest version of the 401 Exam. i have been to all usual Sources like the trailhead or workbooks but i am curious if anyone knows anything that is extremely helpful and easy to understand. 
I have only been studying for about a month and half  and don't have have much development or programming experience.  I am looking to change my career.

Answer (score 5):

Salesforce.com in no longer offering dev 401 certification from Sep 14. Instead of dev 401 you can go for a Salesforce Platform App Builder certification this is completely for a configuration role which involves no development. If you are interested in Developer certification and you have atleast 1-2 years of development experience on force.com platform you can give Salesforce  Platform Developer I certification. This certification is on Apex, Visualforce and Lightning skills mostly.

App Builder Certification:

http://certification.salesforce.com/app-builders

App Builder Study Guide:

http://certification.salesforce.com/SG_CertifiedPlatformAppBuilderTransition.pdf

Platform Developer Certifications:

http://certification.salesforce.com/platform-developers

Platform Developer study Guide:

http://certification.salesforce.com/SG_CertifiedPlatformDeveloperI.pdf

Here are some sample questions for App Builder Exam:

http://www.cloudprofessionals.biz/salesforce-certified-app-builder-exam-questions-part-1-sample-questions/

What To and How to study for App Builder:

[Salesforce Certified Platform App Builder Exam](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/91453/salesforce-certified-platform-app-builder-exam/91480#91480)